# How to split the_content() after some paragraph

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add Advertisement after end 7 th paragraph ,after end 22 paragraph and after end 30 th paragraph on my the_content(). How can i do it ?

I try to used below code but there have foreach section because of that i cant used another loop under foreach

```
<?php 
                $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
if( substr_count( $content, '<p>' ) > $insert_after )
{
    $closing_p_tag = '</p>';
    $contents = explode( '</p>', $content );
    $p_tag_counter = 1;
    foreach( $contents as $content )
    {
        echo $content;
 echo $closing_p_tag;
        if( $p_tag_counter == 7)
        {
        ?>

<?
        }
        echo $closing_p_tag;

        if( $p_tag_counter == 22)
        {
        ?>

<?
        }
        echo $closing_p_tag;

        if( $p_tag_counter == 30)
        {
        ?>
<?
        }
        echo $closing_p_tag;
        $p_tag_counter++;


    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the point of the `if`'s? You're just outputting empty lines?

Comment: I would also strongly recommend that you stop using short tags (`<?`) to open PHP-blocks and start using `<?php` instead. Short tags are disabled as default since a bunch of versions back.

Comment: Duplicated https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58605/insert-ad-code-in-the-middle-of-a-post